# Convert positive value to negative value in swift

Tags: swift, negative-number, negate

I want to convert a positive value to a negative value, for example:

```
let a: Int = 10
```

turn it to `-10`, my current idea is just use it to multiple `-1`

```
a * -1
```

I'm not sure if this is proper, any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `-` operator.

```
let negativeA = -a
```

Answer (score 21):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you can use one of the two following ways in order to convert an integer into its additive inverse.

---

## #1. Using `negate()` method

`Int` has a [`negate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2884785-negate) method. `negate()` has the following declaration:

```
mutating func negate()
```

> Replaces this value with its additive inverse.

The Playground code samples below show how to use `negate()` in order to mutate an integer and replace its value with its additive inverse:

```
var a = 10
a.negate()
print(a) // prints: -10
```

```
var a = -10
a.negate()
print(a) // prints: 10
```

Note that `negate()` is also available for all types that conform to [`SignedNumeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/signednumeric) protocol.

---

## #2. Using the unary minus operator (`-`)

The sign of a numeric value can be toggled using a prefixed `-`, known as the [unary minus operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html). The Playground code samples below show how to use it:

```
let a = 10
let b = -a
print(b) // prints: -10
```

```
let a = -10
let b = -a
print(b) // prints: 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately with a Double, if the value is zero, you get "-0" which is odd (but valid).